# Chopped up output using message() in an R Markdown / knitr report

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, r-package

I recently submitted a package to [rOpenSci](https://github.com/ropensci/onboarding), and they prefer the use of `message()` rather than `cat()` for user-side console output. When I made the switch for my package, I noticed a disconcerting change in the formatting of the rendered vignettes. I have reproduced the problem in the following R Markdown report.

````
---
title: "MWE"
author: "Will Landau"
date: "11/20/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r testcat}
for(x in LETTERS[1:3]){
  cat(x, "\n")
}
```

```{r testmessage}
for(x in LETTERS[1:3]){
  message(x)
}
```

```{r testmessage2}
for(x in LETTERS[1:3]){
  message(x, "\n", appendLF = FALSE)
}
```
````

For the first code chunk, I get the desired output: all three lines string together in a single gray box.

```
## A 
## B 
## C
```

But for the second and third chunks, each line is given its own separate gray box.

```
## A
```

.

```
## B
```

.

```
## C
```

How do I keep using `message()` without chopping up the `knitr` output like this?

Comment: On a different note, was it a package already on CRAN or you submitted it to ropensci before CRAN?

Comment: Is there a specific reason they are requesting to use `message` instead?  By default `message` outputs to stderr which is why I think you're seeing this issue - it's the same reason errors get their own lines.  From the `message` help page: "The default handler sends the message to the stderr() connection."

Comment: I am using `message()` now because [rOpenSci prefers it](https://github.com/ropensci/onboarding/blob/master/packaging_guide.md#-console-messages), claiming that it is easier for the user to suppress than `cat()`. The package itself has been on CRAN for nearly a year and is only now (hopefully) moving to rOpenSci as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it: `knitr` has a `collapse` chunk option. All I needed was to put this chunk before any of the other chunks.

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```
````

The output is more condensed than I expected, but after some touching up, the formatting actually looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and build the string and put the message function outside the loop, like this:

````
```{r testmessage}
single_message <- c()
for(x in LETTERS[1:3]){
  single_message <- paste(single_message , x, sep = "\n")
}
message(single_message )
```
````

Note that this example does add a newline at the start, you can prevent this with an extra `if`, or use the first element outside the loop to initialize `single_message`.

Comment: Sorry, my package is such that I cannot consolidate all the messages together beforehand.